# Questionnaire list q&a in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a typer in a Justice court. All the time topping Q and then the question. Then Enter and then A for answer.
I thought: why isn't there a way to automatically write those, just like when you write 1. and it automatically adds 2 when you press Enter?

Bottom line: I want to be able to have automatically written Q when I press Enter, and the next time I press Enter I'll have A written automatically.

Thank you to everyone in advance!! (First time I use stack overflow :D )

Comment: You can use [macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c)

Comment: Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the [help] about what Stack Overflow is for and what kinds of questions are on-topic here. This is not a free code-writing service or a teaching forum. A question needs to show effort and ask about a very specific problem with code you've written. What you ask can be achieved without code using *styles* linked to a numbering system where `Q` and `A` are part of the numbering format. Try asking about this in an end-user venue such as Super User.